# UIWebView different size from Safari

Tags: ios, uiwebview

I am creating a simple app that loads a UIWebView without any address bar.  The web page (when I run it on the simulator) does not look like it does in Safari.  In my app, it cuts off about 10% of the right side of the page.  I am unable to upload an image of it due to my low reputation.  Could anyone help me on this?  Thanks.

**EDIT:**

I uploaded this on prntscr.com.
App Image:
http://prntscr.com/8w2iz3
Safari:
http://prntscr.com/8w2p1u

Comment: post the image as a link, a mod will edit the question and display the image if it is helpful.

Comment: does not really matter, upload it anywhere.

Comment: There it is!  I had to open the simulator.

Comment: Actually, this shows about... half of the website

Comment: may be even better if you provide a screenshot of the device showing the website via safari - for comparison.

Comment: Huh... ok.  I'll try that.

Comment: there it is on safari

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`UIWebView` has a property called `scalesPageToFit` which by default is set to `false`. If you set this property to `true` the loaded web content will be scaled to fit into the `UIWebView`.

```
webview.scalesPageToFit = true
```

Comment: Ah... yes I just tried doing that in Interface Builder.  It fits perfectly, thanks a bunch!